# Cleaning up a Task in an AsyncDisposable (VSTHRD003)

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a class which creates a `Task` which runs during its whole lifetime, that is, until `Dispose()` is called on it:

In the constructor I call:

```
_worker = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueueAsync(_workerCancellation.Token), _workerCancellation.Token);
```

The way I currently do it (which I am also not sure is the right way) is cancelling the `CancellationToken`, and waiting on the task.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_isDisposed)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    _workerCancellation.Cancel();
    _worker.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
    _isDisposed = true;
}
```

When I do the same in the `AsyncDispose` method like so:

```
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    await _worker;
}
```

I get [this warning](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md)

How do I correctly dispose of such a worker? Thanks!

As requested, here is the full code of what I am trying to do:

```
public sealed class ActiveObjectWrapper<T, TS> : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private bool _isDisposed = false;
    private const int DefaultQueueCapacity = 1024;
    
    private readonly Task _worker;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _workerCancellation;
    
    private readonly Channel<(T, TaskCompletionSource<TS>)> _taskQueue;
    private readonly Func<T, TS> _onReceive;

    public ActiveObjectWrapper(Func<T, TS> onReceive, int? queueCapacity = null)
    {
        _onReceive = onReceive;
        _taskQueue = Channel.CreateBounded<(T, TaskCompletionSource<TS>)>(queueCapacity ?? DefaultQueueCapacity);
        _workerCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _worker = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueueAsync(_workerCancellation.Token), _workerCancellation.Token);
    }

    private async Task ProcessQueueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await foreach (var (value, taskCompletionSource) in _taskQueue.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = _onReceive(value); // todo: do I need to propagate the cancellation token?
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(exception);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<TS> EnqueueAsync(T value)
    {
        // see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-danger-of-taskcompletionsourcet-class/
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TS>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

        await _taskQueue.Writer.WriteAsync((value, completionSource));

        return await completionSource.Task;
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        _taskQueue.Writer.Complete();
        _workerCancellation.Cancel();
        
        await _worker;
        
        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the link?

Comment: Oups, thanks. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Doesn't your link describe how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand it. I'm not sure how relevant it is in my context.

Comment: Post your *actual* code. What does `ProcessQueueAsync` do? A task isn't a thread, it represents a single job. NET already has a class that processes messages posted in its message queue, [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-5.0). You can also use [Channel<T>](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) to implement your own queue worker.

Comment: `how relevant it is in my context.` the analyzer detected that you started a task in one sync context but now try to await it in another. It's about the rest of your code and how it calls your class. Eg you started the task in a background thread and now try to await it in the UI thread. If that task made an `Invoke` on the UI thread you'd end up with a deadlock. You can avoid this problem (and many more) if you don't try to use `Task` as a thread

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using the Channel<T> to do exactly that, but the reader has to run in its own Task for concurrency?

Comment: No. That's why you have to post your code. Besides, with a Channel you need to call `ChannelWriter.Complete()`, not use a cancellation token

Comment: @Ynv you tried to implement an ActionBlock with a Channel. There's no need for so much code. In fact, this isn't a proper way to use Channels. There's a reason ChannelReader and ChannelWriter are separate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the hint with the ActionBlock, I will look into that. My goal here is to serialize access to a shared resource, and I'll try to figure out if this is also what the Block would allow me to do. Since ActionBlock requires me to add another dependency, how would you do it without the library?

Comment: @Ynv it's not another dependency. Most .NET classes are available through NuGet packages. I posted an answer that shows how to use both Dataflow blocks and Channels to create pipelines

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern that I use when implementing both `IDisposabe` and `IDisposeableAsync`. It isn't strictly compliant with the .Net recommendations.  I found that implementing `DisposeAsyncCore()` was unnecessary as my classes are sealed.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    //GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    Worker.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
public void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (isDisposed)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (disposing)
    {
        lock (isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposed)
            {
                return;
            }
            Cts.Cancel();
            Cts.Dispose();
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    //GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    await Worker;
}
```

Comment: `implementing DisposeAsyncCore() was unnecessary.` your code blocks. The whole purpose of `DisposeAsync` is to avoid blocking

Comment: `DispoeAsync` doesn't block. `DisposeAsyncCore` is only necessary if the class isn't sealed. Which is why I didn't need it. If you invoke the class is a `using()` then it will block on `Dispose`. If you invoke  the class with `async using()` then the framework will call `DisposeAsync`

Comment: There's no `DisposeAsyncCore` in the question or this answer. I thought you meant `DisposeAsync` but .... your code is still vulnerable to that warning. If `Worker` was created in another sync context, `await Worker` will still complain. The analyzer has no way of knowing whether that task was cancelled.

Comment: Yep. I guess we have to see the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks interesting. What is the reason for passing the bool `disposing`?

Comment: It's just a standard pattern. The finalizer would call Dispose(false) but if you have no finaliser and your class is sealed it's really moot.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an attempt to build a `TransformBlock<TIn,TOut>` on top of Channels. Using a Channel properly wouldn't generate such a warning. There's no reason to use a single processing task, or store it in a field.

**Using Blocks**

First, the equivalent code using a TransformBlock<Tin,TOut> would be:

```
var block=new TransformBlock<TIn,TOut>(msgIn=>func(msgIn));
foreach(....)
{
   block.Post(someMessage);
}
```

To stop it, `block.Complete()` would be enough. Any pending messages would still be processed. A TransformBlock is meant to forward its output to other blocks, eg an ActionBlock or BufferBlock.

```
var finalBlock=new ActionBlock<TOut>(msgOut=>Console.WriteLine(msgOut));
block.LinkTo(finalBlock,new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion = true});

...
block.Complete();
await finalBlock.Completion;
```

**Using Channels**

Doing something similar with channels doesn't need explicit classes, or `Enqueue/Dequeue` methods. Channels are build with separate ChannelReader, ChannelWriter interfaces to make it easier to control ownership, concurrency and completion.

A similar pipeline using channels would require only some methods:

```
ChannelReader<string> FolderToChannel(string path,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    Channel<int> channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded();
    var writer=channel.Writer;
    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
            foreach(var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
            {
                await _writer.SendAsync(path);
                if (token.CancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
    },token).ContinueWith(t=>_writer.TryComplete(t.Exception));
    return channel;
}
```

This produces a reader that can be passed to a processing method. One that could generate *another* reader with the results:

```
static ChannelReader<MyClass> ParseFile(this ChannelReader<string> reader,CancellationToken token)
{
    Channel<int> channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded();
    var writer=channel.Writer;
    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        await foreach(var path in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
        {
            var json= await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
            var dto= JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json); 
            await _writer.SendAsync(dto);
        }
    },token).ContineWith(t=>writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);
    return channel;
}
```

And a final step that only consumes a channel:

```
static async Task LogIt(this ChannelReader<MyClass> reader,CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async ()=>{
        await foreach(var dto in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dto);
        }
    },token);
}
```

The three steps can be combined very easily:

```
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();

var complete=FolderToChannel(somePath,cts.Token)
                 .ParseFile(cts.Token)
                 .LogIt(cts.Token);

await complete;
```

By encapsulating the channel itself and the processing in a method there's no ambiguity about who owns the channel, who is responsible for completion or cancellation